# What is the difference between photobleaching and photoinduced transparency?

Tags: optics, terminology, spectroscopy, photonics

In experiments on pump-probe spectroscopy, when the pump and probe pulses are close in frequency, there is a common situation when probe pulse absorption decreases (and transmission increases) after pump due to Paulu blocking of optical transitions by carriers which are already excited by the pump. In many papers this effect is called **photobleaching**, however the term **photoinduced transparency** can be also met in the literature.

Is there any difference between these phenomena (perhaps the latter refers to some coherent effects?) or they are just synonyms?

**Update:** here is just one example how the term "bleaching" is used to describe transient changes of transparency due to electron population redistributions: [S. Che et al., Nature Communications 7, 10768 (2015).](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms10768)

> For the 1.86 eV dynamics, the increased probe transmission is typically attributed to the ground-state bleaching, where the increased occupation probability of electrons in conduction band and holes in the valance band leads to the reduced probe absorption, that is, increased $\Delta T/T_0>0$. [image]

Comment: Photobleaching can also indicate a damage to the sample. I know it is the trivial case working with powerful light... This is just a note, in fact. But semantically it is correct and often it means right that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoinduced transparency is mostly referred to as [saturation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturable_absorption). At low light intensity the medium absorbs a lot of light, because nearly all of the atoms/moelcules are in the ground state. In the limit of very high intensity half of the atoms/molecules are excited, so in an oversimplified picture an incoming photon has equal chances of being absorbed or being duplicated by stimulated emission. This averages to an overall absorption going to $0$ and therefore the material becomes tranparent.

Bleaching is when a material permanently changes its optical properties, typically because of a chemical reaction. In particular [photobleaching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photobleaching) is a reaction enabled by the absorption of a photon. A molecule/atom in the excited state is much more likely to undergo a reaction when it's in the excited state, because it comes with a lot of energy, which is potentially helpful to overcome the activation energy of the reaction.

For the sake of completeness let me also mention [blinking](https://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.277.5329.1059). This is when a single molecule relaxes from its excited state not into the ground state, but into another, metastable state. Depending of which metastable state it remains there for a few microseconds up to several seconds before it relaxes into the ground state. If this metastable state doesn't interact with the excitation light the molecule can't emit a photon during that time. So there are streaks when the molecule emits photons normally and dark times, hence it looks like the molecule blinks.

In the paper you linked the effect termed *ground-state bleaching* is actually just depletion of the ground state due to the pump pulse, which makes the sample transparent to the probe pulse. 
[image]
I would definitely not call this bleaching, because it's reversible. And in fact the relaxation dynamics are the topic of the paper. Whenever they call it bleaching they reference to [Sim *et al.* PRB **88** (2013)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.88.075434) (reference 35), in which the phenomenon is described in terms of level population.

I guess this teaches us to not rely on people using the same strict definitions of phenomena, but rather on the details of the process.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! However the term "bleaching" is also frequently used for transient picosecond-scale conductivity changes in solids due to electron-hole excitations without any chemical reactions (see the update to my question). So maybe this term usage is incorrect or slangy, and "photoinduced transparency" should be used instead for correctness?

Comment: @AlexeySokolik I would consider it a chemical process if an emitter loses an electron to the conduction band, which is subsequently drifting away. But in the linked paper they deal with reversible processes, for which the word _bleaching_ is definitely not a good choice. I've added a paragraph to my answer.